# Open sets sandwiched

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a compact metric space and $U$ is a connected open subset of $X$ and $V$ is an open subset of $X$ contained in $U$. Does there exists a compact set $K$ such that $V\subseteq K\subseteq U$?

For instance if $U$ is a ball and $V$ is a strictly smaller ball, then yes.

In case, $X=\mathbb{R}$ (I know not compact) then $U=(a,b)$. So, yes.

Answer (score 3):

The closure of $V$ is compact, and it's the smallest compact set that contains $V$. So a necessary and sufficient condition is $\bar V \subseteq U$. This however doesn't hold in general, for a simple example, take $U=V$.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I meant $V$ is a strict proper subset of $U$ as indicated by examples

Comment: Again, it doesn't hold in general. Let $V=(0,1)$ and $U=(0,2)$, then $\bar V=[0,1]$ is not contained in $U$.